# Mathematica 12.1 start-up time in Linux extremely slow

Tags: interface, timing, kernel-startup, user-interface

I installed Mathematica 12.1 on my Linux machine and the start-up time is extremely slow. 
I see the Spikey logo and messages like:

```
Initializing Kernel connections
```

It takes about 45 seconds to open a standard small notebook.

Running `SystemInformation[]`, I get:

```
{
{" Version", "12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"},
{" Release ID", "12.1.0.0 (6765490, 2020031402)"},
{" Patch Level", "0"},
{" Activation Key", "XXXX"},
{" Machine ID", "XXXX"}
 }

{
{" Machine Type", "PC"},
{" Operating System", "Unix"},
{" Processor Type", "x86-64"}
 }
```

I also can see under `Packages & Files` that 88 packages and 221 files were loaded.

Is someone else experiencing the same problem?

I also have Mathematica 11.2 installed and there, the start-up time is about 2 seconds or less. All the messages from the Spikey logo are shown really fast.
Looking at how many Packages & Files have been loaded, I see 30 packages and 183 files.

Could this be the problem?
I have 16GB RAM and an Intel i7-8650U CPU.

Comment: My Debian Buster VM takes approx 5 seconds for the kernels to fire up.  Did you try renaming ~/.Mathematica out of the way?

Comment: @vsht, what does ``FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`$StartTimes]`` return?

Comment: @ihojnicki This https://pastebin.com/Ff6q7cNQ

Comment: @vsht, well... of the 10+ seconds it took the FrontEnd to start up, 4.84 are waiting for the kernel to finish starting.  Narrowing it down further than that is not straight forward.  I would contact technical support.

Comment: @ihojnicki Ok, it's now [CASE:4938819]. For the record, I'd be really interested in getting this fixed.

Comment: @ihojnicki Although I reported the problem, it seems that you guys mainly test against Ubuntu, so the support is hardly interested in debugging Fedora (which is what later becomes RHEL, BTW) issues. Are there any "adjusting screws" that I could try to solve the problem? It really sucks to way 30+ secs for Mma to start, while v. 12.0 fires up in no time ...